# Adding a Pool of Threads in a RxJava Flow

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, rx-java

I was wondering if I can use the **RxJava** library in order to add some concurrency in the following use-case:

- Fetch sequentially a `String` column from an existing `ResultSet` with a custom `Observable` (something like `ResultSetObservable.create(resultSet)`)
- Invoking a Web Service for each of these value (with a `InvokeWebServiceFunc1<String, Pair<String, Integer>>()` instance, for example) in order to retrieve some statistiques related to the `String` (note that the `String` in the `Pair` is the same as the one passed in input)
- Print everything in a CSV format (with a `ExportAsCSVAction1<Pair<String, Integer>>(PrintStream printStream)`).

So here is what I have:

```
ResultSetObservable.create(resultSet)
    .map(new InvokeWebServiceFunc1<String, Pair<String, Integer>>())
    .subscribe(new ExportAsCSVAction1<Pair<String, Integer>>(System.out));
```

It works well but as the Web Service may take some time for some of the `String` input, I want to add some concurrency by **having a thread pool like behavior for the mapping** (of 10 threads for example) but I *need* the `ExportAsCSVAction0` to **be called in the same thread** (and actually the current thread would be perfect).

Can you please help me? I can't figure if using the `toBlocking().forEach()` pattern is the right solution here and I do not understand where to use the `Schedulers.from(fixedThreadPool)` (in the `observeOn()` or in the `subscribeOn()`).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found it by myself!

```
package radium.rx;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class TryRx {

    public static Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Throwable {
        final List<Integer> inputs = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
        final ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        Iterable<Integer> outputs = Observable.<Integer>from(inputs)
                .flatMap((Integer input) -> deferHeavyWeightStuff(input).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadPoolExecutor)))
                .toBlocking()
            .toIterable();

        for (Integer output : outputs) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
    }

    public static void sleepQuietly(int duration, TimeUnit unit) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(unit.toMillis(duration));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public static Observable<Integer> deferHeavyWeightStuff(final int input) {
        return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(doHeavyWeightStuff(input)));
    }

    public static int randomInt(int min, int max) {
        return RANDOM.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }

    public static int doHeavyWeightStuff(int input) {
        sleepQuietly(randomInt(1, 5), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        int output = (int) Math.pow(input, 2);
        return output;
    }

}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, the output seems to be in a different order than the input. Any clue on how to fix it.

Comment: That is to be expected when parallelizing.

Comment: see the random sleep time function